# How do i get the response from Node.js server in iOS app?

Tags: ios, json, node.js, swift, codable

I have a Node.js server that sends JWT(JSON Web Token) as response, when user logs in. How do I get the response in my Swift 4, iOS app?

```
func handleLogin() {

    guard let username = usernameTextField.text, let password = 
    passwordTextField.text else {
        print("Invalid form")
        return
    }

    guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate") 
    else { return }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let authUser = Login(username: username, password: password)
    do {
        let jsonBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(authUser)
        request.httpBody = jsonBody
    } catch {}

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request)

    task.resume()
}
```

It sends the username and password to the server, but what do I do from here to get the response? The response is a JWT token, and how and where do i store it?

Here are the structs.

```
struct Login: Encodable {
    let username: String
    let password: String
}

struct User: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let username: String
    let email: String
}

struct Response: Decodable {
    let token: String
    let user: User
}
```

Comment: Instead of having an empty catch, print the error that is caught; perhaps your decode is failing.

Comment: What it is printing `sentPost`?

Comment: Can you post `loginUser` sample? Can you post sample data what you are expecting in data?

Comment: It doesnt print anything..

Comment: Can you post sample format of data you are expecting?

Comment: @ViniApp Posted it now.

Comment: Its not there. You said that you are expecting token.

Comment: I need the sample format of data. Otherwise I can't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, _, _) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let _ = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: You copied my answer and then you accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the post, Iam guessing your response will be in the below format :

```
{
    "token": "JWT 2424234234234",
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "user.username",
        "email": "user.email"
    }
}
```

For the above JSON you have to decode like below :

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let token: String
    let user: User
}
struct User: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let username: String
    let email: String
}

let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, _, _) in
    guard let data = data else { return }
    do {
        let sentPost = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
        print(sentPost.token)
        print(sentPost.user.id)
        print(sentPost.user.username)
        print(sentPost.user.email)
    } catch {}
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: It doesnt get anything from the server that way, only sends. But thank you anyways for the structs.

Comment: You asked another question right, for that this will be useful